# stubborn underline won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, underline

I am making a text editor, however the remove underline functionality won't work.
working code example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3JbY/)

Here is the code that gives the problem

```
else if (tag == "u") {
    sell = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

    if (selectionIsUnderlined()) {
        node = range.createContextualFragment("<font style='text-decoration: none !important'>" + sell + "</font>");
    } else {
        node = range.createContextualFragment("<u>" + sell + "</u>");
    }

    range.deleteContents();
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: what problem the code gives?

Comment: if i press the "U" button the selected code gets underlined. If i press the "U" button again it detects the underlined code. then it should remove the underling however that does not work

Comment: Might have to do with `createContextualFragment` being an experimental spec. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.createContextualFragment

Comment: Also, I would use spans with classes.

Comment: Haven't seen the `font` tag for quite a while. And it was better without it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issues with removing underline was that the selection did not take into account the wrapping `<u>` element. The content inside `<u>` was removed and new content with `<font>` tag inserted inside `<u>` tag.

I tried to go up one node and check if it is  `<u>` and then remove the node:

```
if (selectionIsUnderlined()) {
    node = range.createContextualFragment(
           "<font style='text-decoration: none !important'>" + sell + "</font>");
    var nd = sel.anchorNode;
    if(nd.nodeName!=='span'){
        nd = nd.parentNode;
    }

    if (nd) {
        nd.remove();
    }
```

The updated fiddle is <kbd>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/X3JbY/2/)</kbd>

**PS:-** this is just an experiment. please consider performance/browser compatibility and other pros/cons before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var node="";
var divs=0;

if (selectionIsUnderlined()) {
   node+="<div class=underline>";
   divs++;
}

if(selectionIsBold()){
   node+="<div class=bold>";
   divs++;
}

node+=sell;
```

Then close your divs.

```
.underline{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

etc..

Comment: Did you try to change the style with jQuery/JS?